# Pass MPMediaItemArtwork into Core Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

If I want to pass a `MPMediaItemArtwork` image into Core Image, what method should I try to use?  I can't seem to figure this out.

I know if it was a `url` then I'd use:

`CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:myURL];`

But I can't figure out what class method to use for the `MPMediaItemArtwork` image.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Do you understand how to obtain the artwork as an image? Do you understand how to derive a CIImage from that? Problem solved.

Comment: @matt Yeah I obtain the artwork as an image with `UIImage *artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (44, 44)];`.  The part I'm having trouble with is "how to derive a CIImage from that".  Specifically, I don't see a class method to use that I can pass `artworkImage` into.  Since its not a `url` I can't use `imageWithContentsOfURL` obviously, and the problem is I'm not seeing an obvious class method to use or one I've tried that works.  I assumed I'd see an `imageWithUIImage:` type method, but I don't see that and am not sure which one to use.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @matt I've looked at this page to try to figure it out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/

Comment: But this is iOS. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIImage/initWithImage:

Comment: Meant to put that one, but I'm not sure if you seem to have seen a method I should be using or not?  Did you see something in there that stood out that I should be using?

Comment: You really don't see `initWithImage:`? I linked you right to it.

Comment: @matt The link didn't jump right to that, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matt said, it is `initWithImage:` that was the perfect solution.